# Geometric Intuition for $\int^b_0 x^p dx= \frac{b^{p+1}}{p+1}$

Tags: calculus, geometry

In Apostol's Calculus, on pg. 80 of Vol. 1, it states that if p is a positive integer and b > 0, we have $\int^b_0 x^p dx= \frac{b^{p+1}}{p+1}$.

Despite going through the provided proof I still feel as if I don't really understand why the above statement is true.

Is there a nice way to see why, geometrically, these two expressions are equal?

Comment: If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then a fundamental theorem states that $\int_a^b f= F(b)-F(a)$.

Comment: I haven't yet learnt about the fundamental theorems of calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand side is $\frac{1}{p+1}$ of the volume of the $(p+1)$-[hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) with length $b$.

If you stack all the $p$-hypercubes from the integral on top of each other, they form a $p+1$ pyramid of the same volume.

Comment: I understand the first part, but not the second. What are the "p hypercubes from the integral"?

Comment: It's easier if you start with $p=2$. Each '$dx$ slice' of the integral is a square. Place all the squares on top of each other to get a pyramid which is dimension $p+1=3$ and which is $\frac13$ the volume of the cube. The 'p hypercubes' form a higher dimensional abstraction of this idea.

Comment: I don't understand how you can slice the integral to create squares, wouldn't the $x^2$ curve make that impossible?

Comment: Don't view $x^2$ as a curve but instead as an $x\times x$ square area. Each $x$ from $dx$ corresponds to a particular square, and stack them up when summing over the integral.

Comment: I don't know if it helps ![https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Zh6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Zh6.png)

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu; that's right, now for $n=3$ and beyond!

Comment: 3 Blue 1 Brown has made an excellent video on a geometric way to understand the derivative of $x^2$ and $x^3$ : https://youtu.be/S0_qX4VJhMQ

Comment: Thank you all for the help, the picture is exactly what I needed.